# Vue.js - v-for to display images horizontally (5 by row)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to get the images from the service and need to display horizontally. Let's say there are 10 images. Then I need to display the first five images in the first row and the next five images in the second row. My attempt it as below.

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px;width: 100%;">
 <div style="display: flex">
    <ul v-for="(item,index) in body_content">
        <li style="width: 20%;display: inline">
          <img v-bind:src="item.title">
        </li>
        <br v-if="index > 6">
    </ul>
 </div>                                                                                
</div>
```

But it doesn't work properly. If anyone knows a way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:grid` and `grid-template-columns:repeat(5,1fr)` properties like :

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px;width: 100%;">

    <ul  style="display: grid;grid-template-columns:repeat(5,1fr);">
        <li v-for="(item,index) in body_content" style="width: 20%;display: inline" >
          <img v-bind:src="item.title">
        </li>
    </ul>
                                                                              
</div>
```

It's recommend to iterate over the `li` not the `ul` and use class names to separate the style and make the template more clean.